# osnadmin channel joins error: consenter has invalid certificate: verifying tls client cert with serial number <serial number>

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-orderer

When I try to join a orderer to a channel with osnadmin pointing to the orderer channel API, it is returning me the following error:

**Status: 400
{
"error": "cannot join: failed to determine cluster membership from join-block: failed to validate              config metadata of ordering config: consenter node0.orderer.green:7050 has invalid certificate:   verifying tls client cert with serial number  : x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
}**

I have used two root fabric-ca's for creating the certificates: one for tls certificates and one for the organization certificates.

The consenter the error is pointing to, is configured in the configtx.yaml as follows:

```
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: node0.orderer.green
          Port: 7050
          ServerTLSCert: ordererOrganizations/orderer.green/orderers/node0.orderer.green/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
          ClientTLSCert: ordererOrganizations/orderer.green/orderers/node0.orderer.green/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
```

These certificates are registered and enrolled from the tls ca. The osnadmin ca-file is the tls ca root certificate and the --client.cert and client.key are pointing to a certificate registered and enrolled on the samen tls ca.

I am using fabric-version 2.3.3, but also tried 2.4.7, same error. I have been trying to figure this out for days already. Any help or tips are appreciated!

I have tried every possible combination of certificates to configure in the configtx.yaml file. Listing the channels with osnadmin on the same orderer channel API works fine.

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I'm experiencing the same issue :(